# Starting any Emacs buffer with a .c extension with a template

Tags: emacs, templates

I write a lot of short throwaway programs, and one of the things I find myself doing repeatedly is typing out code like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

}
```

To save some tendon hits I was wondering if it was possible to insert a simple template above whenever I create a buffer with the extension of .c.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put somthing like this in `.emacs`

```
(define-skeleton c-throwaway
  "Throwaway C skeleton"
  nil
  "#include <stdio.h>\n"
  "#include <stdlib.h>\n"
  "\n"
  "int main(void){\n"
  "\n"
  "}\n")
```

And eval (`C-x C-e`) it. That'll give you a
function (`c-throwaway`) that inserts your template.

To get this inserting automaticly you'll need to activate
`auto-insert-mode`. Once you do this you can `describe-variable
auto-mode-alist` and read up on how emacs does some of its open
file magic. Then define `auto-insert-alist` to apply it when you
find a new file.

Maybe something like this

```
(define-auto-insert "\\.\\([Cc]\\|cc\\|cpp\\)\\'" 'c-throwaway)
```

More detail:

- [Auto Insert Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode)
- [Autotype](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Autoinserting.html)

Comment: Hello Tom: Thanks for this. I tried this right now. But I don't get the #include's - I get everything else. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `define-skeleton` needs one more parameter, before the skeleton contents: a prompt string for a variable `str` that could be used later. This functionality is optional to use, so just putting a `nil` after `"Throwaway C Skeleton"` should get you going, if indeed I'm write on this.  Much more detail at [SkeletonMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode) on emacswiki.

Answer (score 10):

I use template.el from http://emacs-template.sourceforge.net/

Basically, I create a file called ~/.templates/TEMPLATE.c, and then that gets inserted into my .c files.  You can also use special markup and arbitrary lisp expressions, if you don't just want to dump text into the buffer.  I use this feature so that Perl modules start with "package Foo::Bar" when they are named lib/Foo/Bar.pm.  Very handy.

Answer (score 4):

The following function will ask for a filename and then insert a file and change to c-mode.  The only problem is that you have to call this function to create the buffer instead of your normal way.

```
(defun defaultCtemplate(cfilename)
    (interactive "sFilename: ")
    (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer cfilename))
    (insert-file-contents "~/Desktop/test.c")
    (c-mode)
)
```

P.S Thanks for the question, now I know how to do this for myself :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [YASnippet template system](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) for Emacs, which just has a builtin template called `main`. So while writing your code, just type `main`, hit `TAB`, and it will expand it to the form you want. (And you can always write your own snippet templates.)

Comment: I prefer this method, that way i always have a pristine file to begin with, but I can easily fire in a template when needed.

YASnippet also integrates nicely with Anything, which is antoher big win for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use [following code](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/common/emacs/rc/emacs-rc-auto-insert.el.html) to create files from templates. There are several templates, that are substitutes with actual file names, etc

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but this might help someone. Looking at [this site](http://www.postsubmeta.net/MyConfig/Emacs), I copied and pasted this part into my .emacs file:

```
;; automatic insertion of templates
(require 'autoinsert)
(auto-insert-mode)  ;;; Adds hook to find-files-hook
(setq auto-insert-directory "~/Documents/Emacs/templates/") ;;; *NOTE* Trailing slash important
;;(setq auto-insert-query nil) ;;; If you don't want to be prompted before insertion
(define-auto-insert "\.tex" "my-latex-template.tex")
(define-auto-insert "\.cpp" "my-cpp-template.cpp")
(define-auto-insert "\.h" "my-cpp-template.h")
```

After changing the directory and filenames, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it (because I didn't know about auto insert mode :-)

```
(require 'tempo)

(setq c-new-buffer-template 
      '(
        "#include <stdio.h>\n"
        "#include <stdlib.h>\n"
        "\n"
        "int main(void){\n"
        "\n"
        "}\n"
        ))

(defun my-c-style ()
  "My editing style for .c files."
  (c-mode)
  (if (zerop (buffer-size))
      (tempo-template-c-skeleton)))

(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.c\\'" . my-c-style) auto-mode-alist))

(tempo-define-template "c-skeleton" c-new-buffer-template
               nil
               "Insert a skeleton for a .c document")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of [Defaultcontent.el](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/Miscellaneous/defaultcontent.el) and [YASnippet.el](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/).  The former fills brand-new files with default content.  The latter is a sort of lightweight code-gen macro thing.  Key in "for" and hit TAB and the skeleton of a for loop is inserted.  Etc.  You can define your own snippets pretty easily.  "swi TAB" gets you a complete switch statement.  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

[yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) is good at expand template in your file, and is very easy to create your snippets.
auto-insert is good at fill a new file with template, but write your own template is hard. There is a great package [yatemplate](https://github.com/mineo/yatemplate/) bridges the gap between YASnippet and auto-insert-mode, i can write auto-insert rules with YASnippet.